# Sorting string column Qgis

Tags: qgis, string

I would like to order my field like "normal" but as this column is string it won't work. 
I got "Emplacement réservé 105";"Emplacement réservé 106"; .... before "Emplacement réservé 20".

What should I do? to have 
Emplacement réservé 10
Emplacement réservé 25
Emplacement réservé 99
Emplacement réservé 105
Emplacement réservé 105

[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since QGIS 2.16 you can sort by whatever expression you'd like.

Right click the attribute table header, click on Sort and enter the expression you want.

E.g. extract the interesting part with a [regular expression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#details)

```
to_int(regexp_substr("your_column", '.*(\\d+)'))
```

[image]

In earlier versions of QGIS (2.14 LTR) the simplest way would be to create a new virtual field with the above expression and use this for sorting.

Comment: This is rather cool. Could you explain this bit please, is it python or something?      '.*(\\d+)'

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are a swiss army knife for pattern matching. The syntax which is used here is described in [the QRegExp help](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#details).

Comment: Thx this is great for the project, but what I need do for the layout section? This sheet as to appear with the "right" sorting in the layout section

Comment: Are you referring to the "print composer"?

Comment: Yes I am. In the print composer I added an attribute table for this layer.

Comment: Not sure. But I'd say it deserves a question as well.

Comment: OK, new question added there: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214909/sorting-string-column-in-print-composer-qgis

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's a string so QGIS sorts it character by character. You have to extract the number as a integer (in your case) with the field calculator and then you will be able to sort it as you want, using something like:

```
replace("TXT", 'ER ', '')
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column in the table and using the field calculator cut the number out of the string using `right()` or`left()` (You can use one inside the other).

If you set the column to type:integer then you don't have to worry about trailing spaces you may have picked up with the difference between 2 and 3 digit numbers, but you won't get a numerically ordered list as QGIS likes to number (e.g: 1,2,3,4,5,27,45) in a weird manner (1,2,27,3,4,45,5). Retain your new column a type:text and a zero to the start of you smaller number (01, 02, 03) and that should then be ordered (e.g: 01,02,03,04,05,27,45).

The left image is an ordered text column, the right image is an order integer column.

[image]

You could create a new column in the table and using the field calculator cut the number out of the string using `right()` or`left()` (You can use one inside the other).

If you set the column to type:integer then you don't have to worry about trailing spaces you may have picked up with the difference between 2 and 3 digit numbers, but you won't get a numerically ordered list as QGIS likes to number (e.g: 1,2,3,4,5,27,45) in a weird manner (1,2,27,3,4,45,5). Retain your new column a type:text and a zero to the start of you smaller number (01, 02, 03) and that should then be ordered (e.g: 01,02,03,04,05,27,45).

The left image is an ordered text column, the right image is an order integer column.

[image]

**UPDATE**

If it's you 'TXT' column you are trying to order by then run these expressions to update the column:

```
trim(substr("TXT",4,3))
```

This extracts just the number and clean any spaces from the string.

```
CASE WHEN length("TXT") < 3 THEN '0' + "TXT" ELSE "TXT" END
```

This will check for any number under 3 digits and add a 0 to the front, leaving the 3 digit numbers alone