# Sorting string column in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, sorting

Previously asked a the same generic question ([Sorting string column Qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214880/sorting-string-column-qgis)), but would need to know a solution in Print Composer. 
A added an atribute table in my print composer, and I need to sort the field.

I would like to order my field like "normal" but as this column is string and it doesn't work out. I got "Emplacement réservé 105";"Emplacement réservé 106"; .... before "Emplacement réservé 20".

What should I do? to have

```
Emplacement réservé 10 
Emplacement réservé 25 
Emplacement réservé 99 
Emplacement réservé 105 
Emplacement réservé 105
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the **integer** field you created from your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214880/sorting-string-column-qgis), you can sort the *Attribute Table* depending on the field by going to:

```
Item properties > Main properties > Attributes...
```

---

**Edit:**

I can think of a couple of options. The first is to create a **virtual field** using the answers from your previous question. This is only saved in the project file and not the shapefile itself.

Another method is to add a new field to the Attribute Table **from the Print Composer** which saves you from adding it to the layer itself and lets you sort your table. To do this:

---

1. Go to:

   ```
   Item properties > Main properties > Attributes...
   ```

   Then click the 'plus' button to add a new column:

   [image: Add field]

---

2. Highlight the first box in the new row and click the *epsilon* button:

   [image: Add expression]

   Use an expression like:

   ```
   to_int(regexp_substr("TXT", 'ER (.*)'))
   ```

   Then click *OK*. The expression will be shown as a heading for the field but you can rename this or set it empty if you so wish.

---

3. Then from the *Sorting* tab, choose the field name with the expression, select how you wish to order it and then click the *plus* button.

   [image: Add new sorting field]

---

4. Finall click *OK* and hopefully your table will include this new field and be sorted accordingly.

Comment: I can't create another field. this is forbidden by the reglementation. I only have thoses 2 field (LIBELE and TXT) I can use

Comment: Use a virtual field

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Yup, good shout =)

Comment: Sweet ! Gotcha 
Now just need to find a way to "hide" this other column. I'm gonna go with a white rectangle I suppose

Comment: @Arthur - Yeh, that might be the best option. Don't think it's possible( yet) to filter out certain columns.